# Raspberry crosscompilation in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, ffmpeg

I want to compile an application for Raspberry in Eclipse (in windows). I installed SysGCC, configured Eclipse for crosscompiling. And if I create something like "Hello world" - everything is ok. Eclipse creates binaries which wonderfully works on Raspberry.
But i need use FFMPEG libraries in my application . Here the minimal code of application:

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

int main(void) {
    av_register_all();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I added libraries in project config. Project compiles good, but linker gives a lot of errors:

```
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\local\lib\libavcodec.a(aaccoder.o): In function `quantize_and_encode_band_cost_template':
/usr/src/ffmpeg/libavcodec/aacenc_quantization.h:108: undefined reference to `cbrtf'
/usr/src/ffmpeg/libavcodec/aacenc_quantization.h:108: undefined reference to `cbrtf'
/usr/src/ffmpeg/libavcodec/aacenc_quantization.h:108: undefined reference to `cbrtf'
/usr/src/ffmpeg/libavcodec/aacenc_quantization.h:108: undefined reference to `cbrtf'
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\local\lib\libavcodec.a(aacenc_is.o): In function `quantize_and_encode_band_cost_template':
/usr/src/ffmpeg/libavcodec/aacenc_quantization.h:108: undefined reference to `cbrtf'
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\local\lib\libavcodec.a(aacenc_is.o):/usr/src/ffmpeg/libavcodec/aacenc_quantization.h:108: more undefined references to `cbrtf' follow
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\local\lib\libavcodec.a(adx.o): In function `ff_adx_calculate_coeffs':
/usr/src/ffmpeg/libavcodec/adx.c:30: undefined reference to `cos'
/usr/src/ffmpeg/libavcodec/adx.c:34: undefined reference to `lrintf'
/usr/src/ffmpeg/libavcodec/adx.c:35: undefined reference to `lrintf'
/usr/src/ffmpeg/libavcodec/adx.c:30: undefined reference to `cos'
/usr/src/ffmpeg/libavcodec/adx.c:34: undefined reference to `lrintf'
/usr/src/ffmpeg/libavcodec/adx.c:35: undefined reference to `lrintf'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ffmpeg] Error 1

02:21:24 Build Finished (took 8s.394ms)
```

SOLVED:

i used next command:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -L"C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\local\lib" -L"C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\lib" -o "ffmpeg"  ./src/ffmpeg.o   -lc -lm -lpthread -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil -lavfilter -lavdevice -lswresample -lpostproc -ldl -lx264 -lgcc -lz
```

where **-lc -lm -lpthread -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil -lavfilter -lavdevice -lswresample -lpostproc -ldl -lx264 -lgcc -lz** are libraries linker needs (maybe not all of them).
please note that order is important.

Comment: If `cos` is missing, do you include `math` library for linking?

Comment: What compiler flags are you using to compile the library? Be sure to enable floating point support.

Comment: Your missing the header files, just look for that in internet and include that in the corresponding C source.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer if compiling works but the linker complains, then the headers are obviously not missing. Instead the library is not included during linking.

Answer (score 0):

do not need compile FFMPEG source for Raspberry PI.
you can install it using apt-get or other package manager, and then you can using 'avcodec.h' to design your app, build by GCC in Raspberry host.